# how can i create a loop that inserts a character after finding a specific character in the string?

Tags: c++, string, loops

im trying to create a loop that inserts a space after each iteration of a period from an inputted string. when i use an if statement, it only modifies the first instance. i dont know how to create a loop that would check for each  period and then insert the space.

i have attempted to create the function with a while loop but it keeps running infinitely.

```
void myfunc(string &s) {

int pos = s.find('.');
if (pos != string::npos) {
pos = s.find('.', pos + 1);
s.insert(pos,"  ");


} 
cout << s;
```

i expect a space after the iteration of a period, but sadly it only modifies after finding the first iteration of such.

Comment: Do you mean that after periods there should be a space in a given string?

Comment: yeah. so a string like "look.run.see" would become "look. run. see:

Comment: Basically loop through the string. Check if it's a period and if there is a space after it.

Comment: i would appreciate it if you could write out that code. my brain isnt working tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close in your thinking. The only thing you were missing was a loop to implement the insert for each `'.'` found in your string. A `for` loop is perfect for this, e.g.

```
void myfunc (std::string& s)
{
    /* loop finding each '.' insert ' ' after (except at end) */
    for (size_t pos = s.find('.');
            pos != std::string::npos; 
            pos = s.find('.', pos + 1)) {
        if (pos + 1 != s.length())      /* don't insert ' ' at end of s */
            s.insert (pos + 1, " ");
    }
}
```

(**note:** there is no need inserting a `' '` at the very end of the string, so a check on `if (pos + 1 != s.length())` is used to test you are not at end before the insert is performed)

Putting it altogether in a full example you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void myfunc (std::string& s)
{
    /* loop finding each '.' insert ' ' after (except at end) */
    for (size_t pos = s.find('.');
            pos != std::string::npos; 
            pos = s.find('.', pos + 1)) {
        if (pos + 1 != s.length())      /* don't insert ' ' at end of s */
            s.insert (pos + 1, " ");
    }
}

int main (void) {

    std::string s {"look.run.see."};
    std::cout << "original: " << s << '\n';

    myfunc (s);

    std::cout << "modified: " << s << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stringinsert
original: look.run.see.
modified: look. run. see.
```

This is not the only way to do it, but a very simple one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::find` function instead of the string `find` function to do this neatly in a loop.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    auto s = std::string {"test.string.here." };
    auto it = s.begin();
    while ((it = std::find(it, s.end(), '.')) != s.end()) {
        it = s.insert(it+1, ' ') + 1;
    }
    assert(s == "test. string. here. ");
}
```

Comment: while this is good code, sadly i am not allowed to use the algorithm header

Comment: Oh. Well go to the algorithm header and copy-paste the code from there into your own file I suppose. Or just rewrite it yourself, it's like 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str="look.run.see.";
   for(int i=0; i< str.size()-1;i++)
   {
    if((str[i]=='.') && (str[i+1] != ' '))
    {
        str=str.substr(0,i+1)+" "+str.substr(i+1,str.size()-1);
    }
   }
   cout<<str;
  return 0;
}
```

This basically checks a string if it has a period and makes sure it doesn't add a space at the end of a string or if there is already a space after it. It could help?